# Message Broker(JMS compliant) options supporting XA Transactions on Azure Cloud

Tags: azure, messagebroker, xa

We are using an enterprise application based on spring boot and atomikos as transaction manager and fully complying with XA Transactions (2PC). Resources used are RDBMS(Postgres)/No SQL DB (Elasticsearch) and Message Brokers (JMS complaint). We were planning to move the application on Azure Cloud but have come across information that there are no message brokers available within Azure supporting XA Transactions. Major JMS brokers there like Azure Service Bus and RabbitMQ are not XA compliant. So, my question is whether there are really no message broker options with XA compliance. In case there are none, what are the options available on Azure, so that we still remain XA complaint. Being an application in the banking domain, we cannot drop XA compliance.